# I am trying to get individual attributes from a DynamoDB table and turn them into variables before callback

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get individual attributes from a DynamoDB table and turn the into variables before callback. I want to callback an Html with the attributes as variables inside the Html document, but I only managed to callback either the whole Item, or a few specific attributes with "ProjectionExpression."
How do I get the items and turn the items in the table into variables before callback?

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    exports.handler = function(evt, context, callback) {

        var params = {
            TableName: 'Item_Get',
            Key: {
            'Item': evt.value,
            },
        "ProjectionExpression": "Price, Description, ItemName"
        };

    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback.error(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
    };
```

Response:

`{
  "Item": {
    "ItemName": "Protein Powder",
    "Price": "59.99",
    "Description": "Chocolate flavored Whey Protein Powder"
  }
}`

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to construct an html document and return that as a response in the callback of the Lambda function? Is that correct?

You should first access the individual pieces of data within the `data` returned to you—e.g. `itemName = data.Item.ItemName;` Then construct your html document using those pieces of data, and return it in a response.

If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do, I think this example will help you: https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-serve-dynamic-html-via-http-endpoint/handler.js.

```
const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
  },
  body: html,
};
callback(null, response);
```